# How can I set up a simple route with areas in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to use Areas so I set up the following:

```
public class ContentAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Content";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Content_default",
                "Content/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

What I would like is for a person who enters the following URL to be directed to a controller inside my Content area.

www.stackoverflow.com/Content/0B020D/test-data

I would like a person entering any URL with "/Content/" followed by six characters to be sent to:

```
- Page action in a controller named ItemController
- Six characters passed as the parameter id
- Optional text after that (test-data in this case) to be put into parameter title
```

How can I do this? I am not very familiar with setting up routes when using areas.

the six digits to be put into a variable called ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're looking for something like

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Content_default",
        "Content/{id}/{optional}",
        new { controller = "ItemController", action = "TheActionYouWantThisToAllRouteTo" }
}
```

This would default everything to one controller and action method (which you have to specify in your instance).  You can then get the data like so:

```
public ActionResult TheActionYouWantThisToAllRouteTo (string id, string optional)
{
    // Do what you need to do
}
```

The way the routes are setup, you can name the pieces of information you want in a URL by wrapping it in a pair of `{ }` curly braces.  If you'd rather the name of `optional` to be `isTestData` then you would just change the route to read `"Content/{id}/{isTestData}"`.

Note: *Since you didn't specify the default action method you want this to route to, I substituted it with `TheActionYouWantThisToAllRouteTo`.  Change that string to read the action method you want this to all go to. This also means you can't have a "regular" controller named ContentController, either.*

**Edit**

Stephen Walther has a good blog post on custom route constraints.  [It can be found here](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx). It should be a good start to get done what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how could I check that the user actually entered just six characters after "/Content/" and not something like /Content/test/abc ?